# How to make a Struct that can be multipled using *

Tags: c#, .net, struct, multiplication

XNA framework for .net has a really useful Object called vector2 that represents a 2d vector..You can multiply them by ints, floats and other Vector 2s

Eg.

```
        Vector2 bloo = new Vector2(5, 5);
        bloo *= 5;
        bloo *= someotherVector2;
```

The only thing is that the X,Y information is stored as floats and in a lot of cases I want to simply store 2d info, or 2d coordinates as ints.
I'd like to make my own struct for this..
Heres what i have..

```
internal struct Coord
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }

    public Coord(int x,int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

My question is how do I make it so my Coord struct can be multipled by ints or other Coords using *  (Not a "Multiply" function call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use operator overloading:

```
public static Coord operator*(Coord left, int right) 
{
    return new Coord(left.X * right, left.Y * right);
}
```

Just put the method into the `Coord` struct. You can do this with many operators like `+,-,/` etc... and also with different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload the [multiplication operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/z19tbbca.aspx) for you type.

```
// overload operator * 
public static Coord operator *(Coord x, Coord y)
{
    // Return a `Coord` that results from multiplying x with y
}
```

Answer (score 1):

overload multiplication operator:

```
public static Coord operator* (Coord multiplyThis, Coord withThis) {
    Coord result = multiply(multiplyThis, withThis); //...multiply the 2 Coords
    return result;
}

public static Coord operator* (Coord multiplyThis, float withThis) {
    Coord result = multiply(multiplyThis, withThis); //...multiply the Coord with the float
    return result;
}
```